# Are relations on Earth not valuable for Muslims?

Tags: jannah, death, relationships, life

Someone said to me that according to Islam a person lives a small part (1/infinity) of his life on Earth and the remainder after he dies in a new place (infinity).  He said, the best parents get rewarded there by God and  the best sons are rewarded etc., before entering to the new place.

If he is selected to enter paradise after this life, they get new partners and they live with their partners without being worried about their death.

Is it really like someone playing in some drama?  In dramas they play some roles for a short interval of time and after that they go back in to their original life?

I mean, are relations on Earth not valuable as this life is temporary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This world is indeed a drama, a deception, an optical illusion.

> "And put forward to them the example of the life of this world, it is like the water (rain) which We send down from the sky, and the vegetation of the earth mingles with it, and becomes fresh and green. But (later) it becomes dry and broken pieces, which the winds scatter. And Allah is Able to do everything." ([18:45](http://legacy.quran.com/18/45))

You live here and it flourishes until it makes you forget that this will all soon be gone and the ever lasting afterlife will soon begin. Thats what life on Earth is. A place where we prepare for the next life. Our actions here determine our place there; either heaven or hell and the status within.

That much is true. However relations are among the most emphasized part of Allahs religion. No religion places greater emphasis on family and brotherhood in the community. Also our relations here, (father, mother, spouse) are our relations in the afterlife. That is one of the comforts promised by Allah in jannah. One will be joined with his family and friends. They will visit each other, play with each other and be together forever and forever in the eternal pleasure of their Lord, without any hunger or fear touching them. In greater comfort and beauty than they had on Earth.
The Prophet Muhammad felt and expressed great love for his children and wives. And he felt very connected with his mother, even though she had died at an early age. His companions also held great love for each other and their families. There are several narrations where they expressed their desire to be joined in the eternal abode of peace with their families.

In fact, Allah has offered in the quran that if the parents and children achieve different statuses in jannah based on their actions, then Allah will raise the one in the lower status to the higher without any decrease of the upper one's status.

Thats why relations in Islam are enduring and forever. For they are for this life and the next one and shall endure for all eternity. Its what gives us great relief at the death of a loved one. The promise that this is merely a temporary parting. We shall meet all our loved ones again. and sooner rather than later.

Remember it is Allah that has placed the love and mercy in our hearts for our families. The Prophet has told us that Allah devided his mercy into 100 portions and placed one on Earth. It is because of this mercy that the animal doesnt eat their young. The mercy and love that a mother feels for her child is all from this portion. and Allah kept the remaining 99 portions for the day of judgement for the believers

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I strongley suggest you to take our [tour] and check our [help].